# Migrating Entity-Framework Core Databeses with Deticated Tenant Databases

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, multi-tenant

We have a multi-tenant application that is using ASP.NET Core and Entity-Framework Core with SQL Server. Each tenant has their own separate physical database but uses the same schema. I was wondering what is a good way to migrate the tenant databases in production using code first migration. Few of the ideas I am considering:

- In Startup.cs ConfigureServices, I loop through all of my tenants and call Migrate() on each of them. I am worried about performance here.
- When the Tenant tries to use the app then the app calls Migrate(); Again, this is not ideal because I cannot guarantee that multiple migrations are called in parallel.
- Generating migration SQL scripts and running them either manually or by using a tool when deploying.

I am looking for ideas on what is the best way to approach this kind of DB migrations.

Comment: Not sure how complex is the migration, but it is usually related to schema changes. I always create db migration SPs to do the work in one or a few transactions. The SP can be called by the deployment tool.

Comment: @PeterHe What do you mean by SPs? Stored Procedures?

Comment: yes, create one or more stored procedures, with one as the entry point for the deployment tool to call.

Comment: The app is using code first ef approach for migrations, so I am not sure how stored procedures are fitting into my app architecture.

Comment: In my opinion, database needs to be developed and maintained separately, code first is the worst for db/project upgrade.

Comment: @gyurisc Which way did you do this, any progress?

Comment: @ibubi we still using the Startup.cs to iterate over the databases and apply migrations but this is not-ideal as it makes the Startup very slow if you have large number of tenant  databases. One idea is to call this migration code in a separate console app and run this migratory console app on deployment.